# next(previous)_post_link() preventing elements from disappearing

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Created a small blog with two buttons and cycle through all the posts.

The issue is, I want to create a better UX experience for my readers. I want the 'previous' and 'next' buttons to stay static. However, once you get to the end (or beginning) of the posts array, one of those buttons disappears. How can I prevent that?

```
 <h3 class="text-white"><?php previous_post_link('%link','previous'); ?></h3></span>
    <span class="ml-5 mr-1"><h3 class="text-white"><?php next_post_link('%link','next'); ?></h3></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<?php
    if (get_adjacent_post(false, '', true)) {
        previous_post_link('%link', '&larr; Previous Post');
    } else {
        $first = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=1&order=DESC');
        $first->the_post();
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">&larr; Previous Post</a>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    };
    if (get_adjacent_post(false, '', false)) {
        next_post_link('%link', 'Next Post &rarr;');
    } else {
        $last = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=1&order=ASC');
        $last->the_post();
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">Next Post &rarr;</a>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    };
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i think this wont be possible, but i got a little workaround-idea:

Check if "next_post_link()" has a callback. If it returns "false" when there is no next post, you can just print out your own button with some HTML.
Same with prev_post_link()